# Выдаётся ошибка в консоли discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Пытаюсь написать простенькую команду на выдачу определенной роли пользователю. Консоль никаких ошибок при запуске не выдаёт, но при вводе данной команды сам бот никак не реагирует, а консоль выдаёт ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import json
import requests
import re
import os
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kid(ctx,client,member:discord.Member, *, role:discord.Role): #сделать ребёнком матери 
    if role in user.roles:
        await ctx.send(f"{user_mention} не может стать ребёнком в квадрате! Это против правил! <:DS_BlobCatAngry:963367204986945556> ") 
    else:
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"{user_mention} официально стал чадом Мамочки! <:DS_BlobCatHeart:963367204856926228> ")
        role = 965288168976969808
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить ваш код на этот

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kid(ctx, member:discord.Member, role:discord.Role): #сделать ребёнком матери 
    if role in user.roles:
        await ctx.send(f"{user_mention} не может стать ребёнком в квадрате! Это против правил! <:DS_BlobCatAngry:963367204986945556> ") 
    else:
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"{user_mention} официально стал чадом Мамочки! <:DS_BlobCatHeart:963367204856926228> ")
        role = 965288168976969808
```

Comment: Это решило одно, но вызвало ещё несколько проблем, а так спасибо)